# Single line text, and multiple text in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement below `UI`, but I failed over and over

[image]

(ignore some blanks) in the above pic

when I tried below code:

```
Row(
  children: [
   Text("text1"),
     Expanded(
      child:Text("text222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222")),
                    ],
                  ),
```

the "text1" is moved to the center of the column (it changes the position vertically)

how to solve this?

EDIT------------

Originally, the baseline of text1 and text2 is the same, but when text2 changes to 2 lines (from 1 line), text1 also falls to the middle. ( I want it to be top not middle, not center)

more simply,

Try implementing 2 texts in a row, and make 2 lines by lengthening only the second text (wrap it with Expanded). Then, the first text changes position suddenly.(to center)

[image]

[image]

-------LAST EDIT

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. try to explain more or add more codes or pictures.

Comment: @Abbasihsn hi I just edited more clearly

Comment: Would it be dynamic? Does text index is the logic for separation?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Originally, the baseline of text1 and text2 is the same, but when text2 changes to 2 lines (from 1 line), text1 also falls to the middle. ( I want it to be top not middle, not center)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the conversation, we need to use  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,`

**Code**

```dart
        Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("text1"),
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                        "text222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222")),
              ],
            ),
```

**Result**

[image]

Does it solve in your case?

Comment: Add `SizedBox` or wrap with `Padding` to have some spaces.

Comment: thanks Yeasin, I actually have a small Container(..shape:BoxShape.circle) in front of  a "text1" but some what their baselines are different do you know why?? the align is not pretty. the Container size is width: 10 height: 10

Comment: can you inclue the code snippet and images,it will be easy for me to get.

Comment: hi this is it the baselines are different //return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            shape: BoxShape.circle
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "text111111111111"
        ),
      ],
    );

Comment: And I just added the pic obviously I can just adjust it using Padding but I think it is not perfect solution because Every devices has different resolution and dpi you know And I just got suspended my account so.. I really hope you leave the advice thanks

Comment: you need wrap `text1` with row and provide `crossAxisAlignment`, hope you want `CrossAxisAlignment.center,`

Comment: I just did what you said now yes it works but Again, container and text1 move to the middle point of text2. So it destroys your first answer. do you have anything else in mind??

Comment: Can you include the full widget and the issue image and an image that you like to archive,  current question doesn't have the content, Or you can create another question.

Comment: I am not able to create new question because of accout status now. I just put it picture lastly thank you

Comment: @marsho you should give margin instead of padding it should not affect that much of the design.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code to test it:

> UPDATE:

```
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text("text1"),
      Text("text2\n2linesffffffffffffffffff"),
      Text("fffffff"),
      Text("fffffffffff")
    ],
  )
```

This will resolve your answer.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think you have misunderstood friend

Comment: update your question in more detail for better understanding. Because most people didn't get your question.

Comment: okay, I update my answer just need to crossAxisAlignment in a row.

Comment: hi thanks for below replying. you think only setting "margin" is the way?